# GNU Fortran - controlling symbol case

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Is there a way to control the case of symbols emitted by GNU Fortran 4.8?

Older versions (such as 3.4) had `-fcase-lower`, `-fcase-preserve` and `-fcase-upper` to force lower case, the case used in the source and upper case respectively, but these seem to have been discarded.  Is there some new way of controlling this?

**Edit**

I'm trying to port a large, mixed C/Fortran, code base from Intel compilers to GNU compilers.

I'm aware that we can use `BIND(C, name='...')` to give a case-specific symbol name.  However, that has other effects.  Consider this C function:

```
void print(char *str, size_t len) {
    for(int ii = 0; ii < len; ii++) {
        putchar(str[ii]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

We can call it from a Fortran program like this:

```
program test
    implicit none
    interface
        subroutine printstr(str)
            character :: str(*)
        end subroutine
    end interface

    call printstr("Hello, world.");
end
```

If the C function name is not all lower-case (`PrintStr`, say) then we might try to fix the Fortran program like this:

```
program test
    implicit none
    interface
        subroutine printstr(str) bind(C, name='PrintStr')
            use iso_c_binding
            character :: str(*)
        end subroutine
    end interface

    call printstr("Hello, world.");
end
```

This doesn't work, though, because the `bind(C, ...)` changes how the string parameter is handled and the length parameter is no longer provided (I'm not sure if this results in stack corruption or just buffer overruns - the example given always segfaults from the buffer overrun).

I think it's probably time for a fresh question on how to sort this out.

Comment: There was a gfortran PR, https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33363 ,  for adding the -fcase-preserve option to gfortran. It was closed as WONTFIX because of a perceived lack of need.  You can reopen that bug and fill in the arguments from this thread (which were not all addressed in the PR). Of course, reopening the PR won't mean that it will be implemented immediately. I do think that a patch implementing -fcase-preserve would be accepted by the gfortran maintainers, though. So... the question is what would be less work for you, modifying gfortran or your own source.

Answer (score 5):

We have searched high and low for exactly this functionality.  In particular, to have case preserved WITHOUT Bind'C.  The extreme "shove" introduced by the powers that be to insist on Bind'C is a terrible outcome for many important circumstances, and especially legacy code, and most especially on Windows.

There is NO CHEAP way of porting legacy or Intel etc mixed language code to gFortran, since, as far as we can tell, many years ago the keepers of GNU Fortran explicitly decided they would NOT keep "preserve-case" or anything like it (I forget the bug report, but you can search for it) saying that there was not sufficient interest ... I must say that sounds a little preposterous, as anyone working in a mixed language environment in Windows will almost surely need a preserve case facility with high frequency.   This is required in VBA/Fortran for DLL's, required in accessing WinAPI s/r's etc etc., and where Bind'C/ISO causes more problems than fixes.

Similarly, they decided NOT to have an ALIAS or something like that attribute in the compiler directives.

Thus, the ONLY mechanism in gFortran (that we know of) that permits preserving case is Bind'C, which is a DISASTER for a variety of reasons, most especially for passing fixed len strings of len > 1.

We use two different, and highly unsatisfactory, solutions styles for mixed lang/interop with gFortran:

1. The MUST PRESERVE case case, such as when interfacing to a WinAPI:

   Interface
   !
   Function w32_GetWindowTextW(hWnd, lpString, nMaxCount) bind(C,name="GetWindowTextW")
   !
   ! from c:\Windows\System32\User32.dll
   !
   Use, Intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, Only: c_IntPtr_t, c_Size_t, c_Int, c_Ptr, c_Char
   !
   !GCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: w32_GetWindowTextW, hWnd, lpString, nMaxCount
   !
   Integer(c_Int)                              :: w32_GetWindowTextW
   Integer(c_IntPtr_t), Value                  :: hWnd                     ! NOTE: this is SUPPOSED TO BE a Win HANDLE, this seems ISO equivalent
   Character(Kind=c_Char)                      :: lpString(*)
   Integer(c_Int), Value                       :: nMaxCount                ! NOTE: this is SUPPOSED TO BE WinAPI int type, this seems ISO equivalent
   End Function w32_GetWindowTextW
   !
   End Interface

Here the preserve case is essential, since otherwise the interface won't find entry point in the WinAPI.  Also, the Bind'C allows aliasing that is otherwise not available, for some strange reason, with GCC FPP.

The GCC compiler directives are required to overcome the Bind'C's destruction/alteration of the calling convention, and revert it back to STDCALL, as required with WinAPI (and also with VB, Excel/VBA etc etc).

However, look at the "dogs breakfast" required to deal with lpString var, where it must now be a vector or Len=1's.  This is a very expensive re-write (and not only in the declarations, but everywhere those vars are used, at the very least an extra layer must be added to convert the Len=1 char array to the original fixed len char vars).

2. Case where it would be "nice" to preserve case, but it is "cheaper" to use all lower case, such as with, say VBA/Fortran interop for creating DLL's as Excel Add-Ins.

ASIDE: the following relies on a custom implementation of erf's in our own libs, but quite a good one is available as an intrinsic.

You could go Bind'C and preserve case (with all the "string implications"), such as

```
Function Erf_Math_BindC_XL(x) bind(C,name="Erf_Math_BindC_XL")
!
Use ARTMathFuncsMod, Only: MathErf  ! Proprietary alternative to Fortran2008 intrinsic Erf()
!
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, STDCALL :: Erf_Math_BindC_XL
!
Real*8                   :: Erf_Math_BindC_XL
!
Real*8, Intent(In)       :: x
!
Erf_Math_BindC_XL = MathErf(x)
!
End Function Erf_Math_BindC_XL
```

By comparison, you could use, instead:

```
Function Erf_Math_XL(x)
!
Use ARTMathFuncsMod, Only: MathErf  ! Proprietary alternative to Fortran2008 intrinsic Erf()
!
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, STDCALL :: Erf_Math_BindC_XL
!
Real*8                   :: Erf_Math_XL
!
Real*8, Intent(In)       :: x
!
Erf_Math_XL = MathErf(x)
!
End Function Erf_Math_XL
```

However, if you compile this directly with gFortan the entry name will be decorated and look something like `_erf_math_xl@4`.

So, if you already had a VBA declaration relying on "Erf_Math_XL", then it will fail.

Now, you can either re-write all of the VBA side ... very expensive, and the "@nn" changes every time you change the arg list, so in reality "geometrically more expensive".

By contrast, if on the gFortran-side you use -fno-underscore, and -mrtd, then the entry names will become simply `erf_math_xl` .  OK, so it is not preserved case, but they are all lower case, and "undecorated".  This can be handled in a less expensive manner compared to re-writing many fixed len strings to len=1 arrays, etc.

Then on the VBA-side the Function/Sub declaration do permit ALIAS so the "case issue" is a relatively simple "edit/replace macro"

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to approach this using the Fotran iso_c_binding module.

First, the C code, just as in your example:

```
void PrintStr(char *str, size_t len)
{
   for (int ii=0; ii < len; ++ii)
     putchar(str[ii]);
   putchar('\n');
}
```

and a suitable Fortran interface for it:

```
interface
  subroutine printstr_c(str, len) bind(C, name='PrintStr')
    use iso_c_binding, only: c_char, c_size_t
    implicit none
    character(kind=c_char) :: str(*)
    integer(c_size_t),value :: len
  end subroutine printstr_c
end interface
```

This will let you call the C function as:

```
character(len=20) :: string = 'Hello ISO C env!'
call printstr_c(string, int(len(string),kind=c_size_t))
```

This works, but requires the length argument to be specified explicitly.  We can do a bit better and create a Fortran function wrapper around it to hide the length from callers.

```
subroutine printstr(str)
  use iso_c_binding, only: c_size_t
  implicit none
  character(len=*) :: str
  call printstr_c(str, int(len(str),kind=c_size_t))
end subroutine
```

Now we can just call:

```
character(len=20) :: string = 'Hello ISO C env!'
call printstr(string)
```

Note that I haven't bothered with null terminating the string as your C function loops over the length argument.  If you need a null terminator you could add one in the `printstr` subroutine.

---

If you have many such functions you want to call, all of the form `void f(str, len)`, then we can do a bit more work and further abstract the `printstr` function to just be a generic translator from Fortran character variables to paired char,len variables suitable for an iso_c_binding call.  Consider this example:

```
module cfuncs
  implicit none
  interface
    ! this interface is for an actual C function
    subroutine printstr_c(str, len) bind(C, name='PrintStr')
      use iso_c_binding, only: c_char, c_size_t
      implicit none
      character(kind=c_char) :: str(*)
      integer(c_size_t),value :: len
    end subroutine printstr_c
  end interface
end module

module ffuncs
  use cfuncs
  implicit none
  interface
    ! this interface is to constrain procedures passed to printstr()
    subroutine string_and_len(str, len)
      use iso_c_binding, only: c_char, c_size_t
      implicit none
      character(kind=c_char) :: str(*)
      integer(c_size_t),value :: len
    end subroutine string_and_len
  end interface
contains
  ! this routine takes the C function you want to call and a string to pass
  ! and does the translation to call funct(str,len)
  subroutine printstr(func,str)
    use iso_c_binding, only: c_size_t
    implicit none
    procedure(string_and_len) :: func
    character(len=*) :: str
    call func(str, int(len(str),kind=c_size_t))
  end subroutine
end module

program main
  use ffuncs
  implicit none
  character(len=20) :: string = 'Hello ISO C env!'
  call printstr(printstr_c, string)
end program
```

This is perhaps a bit overkill for this specific example, but it lets one Fortran wrapper call many C functions of the same type signature.  This in turn would only require you to decorate the Fortran calls in the code you are porting to be wrapped by the wrapper function.  For example assuming `printstrc_c` is the foreign interface:

```
! old F77 non iso_c_binding call
call printstr_c("Hello World")
```

turns into

```
! wrapping the old F77 call through our Fortran wrapper handling iso_c_binding
call printstr(printstr_c, "Hello World")
```

---

This isn't as elegant looking as the old way you were doing things, but the new versions of gfortran (3.x gcc was g77, and 4.x is gfortran, afaik a complete rewrite) don't seem to be able to force case preservation.  If you wanted to avoid the mess I demonstrated, another option would be to post-process the compiled Fortran objects prior to linking and rewrite the function names to have proper case, but I'd consider that a worse mess to deal with (and a dirty hack).

Comment: I did consider doing exactly that - `objcopy --redefine-syms` would do the job, I think.  You could even take the linker errors and use `sed` to generate the symbol mappings.  It'd be a bit of a horror to leave for whoever came after me, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no corresponding command-line option in gfortran. That being said, GFortran supports the ISO_C_BINDING feature so you can rename symbols to whatever is valid in C, e.g.:

```
subroutine foo (a) bind(C, name="FoOoF")
  use iso_c_binding
  integer(C_int) :: a
  a = 42
end subroutine foo
```

Comment: Hmmm.  I have a largish code-base of mixed C/Fortran that currently compiles with the Intel compilers and which I've been asked to port to GNU tools.  Are you saying I need to add `BIND(C...)` to **every** subroutine and function called from C (I think about 2,000 routines)?

Comment: Actually it seems it's worse than that, since `BIND(C...)` also changes the calling convention, eg how strings are handled.

Comment: Without `BIND(C...)`, string parameters are Fortran-style strings, with an implicit length parameter and no null-termination.  With `BIND(C...)`, the length parameter is skipped and you have to provide a null termination yourself on the Fortran side.

Comment: Exactly, the `iso_c_binding` itself is almost irrelevant here. The `bind` attribute definitely changes the calling convention and forces passing by reference, disables Fortran hidden arguments and changes the meaning of `value` somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the info. Perhaps we should insist of case sensitive compiling and linking due to the interoperability of Octave and/or MATLAB with Fortran code. Compiling the simplest possible example written in Fortran with Octave, I run into the same problem because the symbol that exist in the library mexPrintf is translated by default in the gfortran compiled object to mexprintf_. Compiling with gfortran -fno-underscoring produces mexprintf. But then using what our friend above described with objcopy I was able to link manually editing the rdef_syms.txt file replacing MEXPRINTF with mexPrintf. However, after linking successfully when I tried to run my mex function I got a message:

```
error: failed to install .mex file function somefile.mex
```

both under Windows 10 MingW64 and Linux WSL (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).

I guess a possible solution is to download the source of the g77 compiler that supports casing and recompile it from scratch. I was doing that when I was on PhD and familiarizing with Linux, but of course this is not the way to go. Perhaps somebody could explain us why "failed to install .mex file function" since the -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE has been defined both in compilation and linking. The process is to run first "mkoctfile --mex -v -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE somefile.f90", to check how the file is compiled. Then I can make a Makefile of my own for future reference. Anyone has any idea how we could fix this? By the way the -flto does not allow objcopy to rename the symbols. But -flto=auto etc is enabled by default by mkoctfile --mex . So one has to remove it in his makefile if he wishes to try objcopy the symbols for a successful linking.

Thank you all for the objcopy hint. I learned something I did not know. But it is not clear at all how to use bindC in Fortran to map the mexPrintf command for example.

Comment: Is this actually an answer or some discussion? There is a whole C-Fortrsn interoperability chapter in Fortran 2003 where you can set the exported or imported symbol to anything. There is no point requiring the processor-dependent linking to be exactly something used in mex. If you have a new question, please open a question post for that. Be aware that these features strongly depend on the operating system, not just the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem specifically while trying to cross-compile mex files for Matlab for windows using x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran in linux (WSL).

This requires me to link against a proprietary .dll file which contains Fortran functions named `MXGETPR`, but gfortran generates symbols for `mxgetpr`.  The `bind(C,...)` approach does renaming these but as others have pointed out it changes the calling convention to C-style which is problematic for some subroutines (namely, those which handle string arguments).

A comment from @Tom got me pointed towards objcopy for renaming these symbols.  Because all my symbols start with `mx*` or `mex*` the following script converts symbols for me:

```
gfortran $(SRC) -o objfile.o --no-underscoreing $(FCFLAGS)
nm objfile.o | awk '/U mex/ || /U mx/ { print $2 " " toupper($2) }' | sort -u > rdef_syms.txt
objcopy --redefine-syms=rdef_syms.txt objfile.o
```

The second line looks for any symbols in `objfile.o` which are undefined and named `mx*` or `mex*`.  It generates a file mapping the lower-case version to an upper-case version.
The sort ensures no entries are duplicated (objcopy doesn't like duplicates).

Initially the output of `nm objfile.o` looks like this:

```
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 T mexfunction
                 U mxcopyreal8toptr730
                 U mxcreatedoublematrix730
                 U mxgetpr
                 U mxgetscalar
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
```

The `rdef_syms.txt` file is generated to take those symbols and uppercase them.  It looks like this:

```
mxcopyreal8toptr730 MXCOPYREAL8TOPTR730
mxcreatedoublematrix730 MXCREATEDOUBLEMATRIX730
mxgetpr MXGETPR
mxgetscalar MXGETSCALAR
```

And finally after the objcopy reads the file and renames the symbols in-place, the object file has the following symbols:

```
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 T mexfunction
                 U MXCOPYREAL8TOPTR730
                 U MXCREATEDOUBLEMATRIX730
                 U MXGETPR
                 U MXGETSCALAR
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
```

Obviously my case was helped by the unique names that I'm trying to remap, and that I'm simply trying to uppercase them rather than some mixed-case solution, but I was surprised that this didn't feel as hack-ish as I expected, and it was only 2 extra lines!